# Typescript not bundling modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a node application that compiles typescript files to a `dist` folder and then serves these files as lambda resolvers via aws cdk. Here is an example of my setup:

### The code

**register.ts**

```
import ValidateUserFields from '../utils/forms';

exports.main = async function (event: any, context: any) {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
    };
}
```

**register-lambda-config.ts**

```
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as apigateway from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import * as s3 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3';

export class FrontendService extends Construct {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);

    const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'frontend-api', {
      restApiName: 'Frontend Service',
      description: 'This service serves the frontend.',
    });

    const functionName = 'register';

    const handler = new lambda.Function(this, functionName, {
      functionName,
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('dist/src/lambda'),
      handler: 'register.main',
    });

    const registerIntegration = new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(handler, {
      requestTemplates: { 'application/json': '{ "statusCode": "200" }' },
    });

    const registerResource = api.root.addResource('register');
    registerResource.addMethod('POST', registerIntegration);
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2018"],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "cdk.out", "./dist/**/*"]
}
```

And finally here is the script part of my **package.json** file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "cdk": "cdk",
    "bootstrap": "cdk bootstrap",
    "deploy": "cdk deploy && rimraf cdk.out",
    "destroy": "cdk destroy",
    "run-same-local-fe-api": "sam local start-api -p 4000 -t ./template.yaml",
    "dev": "npm run build && npm run synth && concurrently --kill-others \"npm run watch\" \"npm run run-same-local-fe-api\"",
    "synth": "cdk synth --no-staging > template.yaml"
  },
```

### The problem

When I run `npm run dev` it compiles my typescript files to the `dist` folder in the same structure as what I have in my `src` folder (where all my typescript files live). I however run into the following error if I have any imports in my `register.ts` file:

> {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot
> find module '../utils/forms'\nRequire stack:\n-
> /var/task/register.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n-
> /var/runtime/index.js","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error:
> Cannot find module '../utils/forms'","Require stack:","-
> /var/task/register.js","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","-
> /var/runtime/index.js","    at _loadUserApp
> (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:202:13)","    at
> Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:242:17)","
> at Object. (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at
> Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)","    at
> Object.Module._extensions..js
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)"," at Module.load
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)","    at Function.Module._load
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)","    at
> Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
> (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)","    at
> internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}

This happens for imports from relative local files (like '../utils/forms' as shown in the code above) but also for imports from node_modules. When I look into the compiled `register.js` file in the `dist` folder I see that it has made an attempt to parse the import:

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const forms_1 = __importDefault(require("../utils/forms"));
const bucketName = process.env.BUCKET;

exports.main = async function (event, context) { ...
```

however it shows the error message above. I have tried using `require` instead of `import` but it was the same result...

Any help would be greatly appreciate! Thanks

Comment: just to be clear, the error occurs during the compile-time and has nothing to do with aws? Maybe you could set up a small reproducible project on github?

Comment: Why are you setting `module: commonjs` but then using `import/export`? Be consistent with your module definitions in the ts config and source code. Have you tried changing everything to ES Modules in your source code and then changing the ts config to `module: esnext`? Also, what is your directory structure like?

Comment: What's the folder structure of your project? Under `src` i mean? I assume that all relative imports live under there? Also, if this error occurs locally as well, then it's better to exclude the CDK / AWS aspect from the equation for now since the problem exists also outside of that context.

Comment: Also, your title is asking about why Typescript doesn't bundle modules, it's because `tsc` is not a bundler; it transpiles source files into a different format which are supposed to be executed in an environment where all the dependencies are available. If they are not, you have to check why the transpiled files can't find the dependencies. To bundle, you can use a bundler like Webpack or Rollup but it should work without a bundler as long as you make sure that you have all transpiled files and `node_modules` in place.

Answer (score 2):

Stated that this is really hard to answer without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); I would at least suggest to avoid any `require` and `exports`, and to use only `import` / `export` statements and following in **tsconfig.json**.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Unfortunately this answer only introduced a separate list of issues which I could not get past. Here is a repo with a reproducible example if you could help? https://easyupload.io/ulnmo4

Comment: If you do a post request to http://localhost:4000/register in Postman or similar you should be able to see the error

Comment: Really? Could you try import the following JSON into Postman and try the request again? https://pastebin.com/vr3MhR5Q

Comment: I think you may be doing a `GET` request as opposed to `POST`

Comment: Yes @redhouse87 I did a get; thank you. Unfortunately I don't know `sam`, I installed it to perform this test. It seems that as `React` compiles only the content of `src` directory, `sam` compiles only the content of the lambda `directory`: moving the `utils` directory inside the `lambda` one, the error disappears. If the purpose to import from another directory is to use some code shared with other projects, the proper way to handle the case is to deploy the shared code as a package (in npm or CodeArtifact) and use it as dependency for all the projects requiring it.

Comment: hmm strange, I wonder why it doesn't compile it

Answer (score 1):

Well.. I do understand that you want your main function to look something like this:

```
// final result written in javascript
exports.main = async function (event, context) {
  return {
      statusCode: 200,
    };
}
```

But... using `module.exports` in `Typescript` is not the way to achieve that. Instead, Typescript using `export` directive (no *s* at the end of it) to define which parts of your code should be export. It's then up to your `tsconfig.json` file to determine which syntax will be used in order to represent this export (this is actually a part of Typescript engine)

So... a script written like this in Typescript

```
export async function main(event: any, context: any) {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
  };
}
```

Will be parse in Typescript as follow (I've used `module: commonjs` to achieve below result)

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.main = void 0;
async function main(event, context) {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
    };
}
exports.main = main;
//# sourceMappingURL=test.js.map
```

Please note how the resulted `js file` correctly use `modile.exports` and `main` as you intended

**In short:** when using Typescript, please use the language directives and let the engine to do the rest for you. This way - a single source of code can be deployed for different environment without requireing changing your app logic. Neat!